# How to fully uninstall and clear Brave-Browser data?

Tags: apt, uninstall, cleanup, brave

Slowly but surely as I use Brave on Ubuntu it looses all functionality, first I can't log into my finances, then I can't download .pdfs, etc... .  I keep clearing all data, purging off apps installed on it (... where did they come from? I didn't install them) and it never gets better.  So I tried uninstalling and reinstalling brave using:

```
sudo apt purge brave-browser
```

and then

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

But after I reinstall it still has all sorts of things associated with from prior to the uninstallation: it has all the book-marks even though I didn't reload them, they were just there, it still can't log in to half of the sites it used to that I need to log into, and it still won't download certain, perfectly ordinary .pdfs or print things.

How does one really truly purge out everything brave-browser so that I can actually get a clean install and get back to work instead of dawdle with its crippled irreparable state?

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, that is clearly the source of my problem.  I would select this as a correct answer if it was an answer not a comment ... I am too low rated to upvote comments so I can't reward you for your useful response as is, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`purge` does not remove user data, caches, and settings that are located in /home.

By design, no apt or snap command will remove files from your /home directory.

You must remove those directories and files from your /home directory manually.